# Postgres text array to hstore

Tags: postgresql, data-conversion, hstore

I have an array of even length, with comma delimited values (not necessarily homogeneous):

```
'{"a", 10000, "b", 20000}'
```

I would like to parse this postgres array into an hstore column, associating each odd entry (index 1,3,...) as a key, and each even entry (index 2,4,...) as value. Is this possible?

Comment: Hstore supports directly construction from a `text[]` based on documentation. Did you try just hstore(array)?

Comment: `hstore('{"a", 10000, "b", 20000}'::text[])` works just fine

Comment: Thanks all - my bad. If you lodge this as answer, I will tag it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sami mentioned, just use:

```
SELECT hstore('{"a", 10000, "b", 20000}'::text[]);
```

Output:

```
           hstore
----------------------------
 "a"=>"10000", "b"=>"20000"
(1 row)
```